# Did Postfix deliver a mail via plain SMTP or STARTTLS?

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp

Using [smtp_tls_security_level](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level) or [smtp_tls_policy_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) I can make Postfix deliver outgoing mail via STARTTLS.  However, the log file doesn't seem to tell me whether the mail was sent using TLS.

```
Jul  9 13:54:07 outgoing.example.com postfix/smtp[1337]: ABCDEF123: to=<alice@example.org>, orig_to=<alice@example.org>, relay=mx.example.org[192.0.2.25]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.01/0/0.34/1, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 Yum yum munch munch)
```

Is there a way to log per outgoing mail whether it was delivered using plain SMTP or STARTTLS?

Comment: Only way to reliably determine if encryption went all the way would be to look at the final set of headers on the messages.  Your outgoing SMTP server may not deliver directly to the highest priority MX for the domain... a common configuration for spam/virus scanning servers is to have a backup mx accept mail and scan and then forward via normal smtp spec , and the primary only accepts from the backup due to firewall or similar

Answer (score 2):

Change default configuration:
[smtp_tls_loglevel](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_logging) for outgoing connections
[smtpd_tls_loglevel](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_logging) for incoming connections

Answer (score 0):

By default Postfix won't log any information about the connection when sending mail (although the recipient may still be able to learn such TLS information from a `Received` header) but you can increase the [`smtp_tls_loglevel`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_loglevel) from the default `0` to `1` or higher.